# jQuery: Audio Player that supports almost all formats

Tags: javascript, audio, jquery-plugins

I need to embed jQuery audio player in my site.the src is coming from DB.the problem is that there is not one fixed format .it can be any like 3gp,mov.ogg.mp3 etc etc

I have searched it and found many jQuery plugins but they all are limited to 2 or 3 formats.
I wonder is there any jQuery plugin that support all formats?

Comment: I think you got something wrong here. jQuery is a DOM manipulating library, all audio playback with the HTML 5 `<audio>` tag is done within the browser. So you have to stick with what the different browsers offer.

Comment: @Constantinius html5 audio is not working in IE7

Comment: IE7 is a tat outdated anyways. If you want to use HTML 5 features, you have to use browsers that support it. 
On the other hand, have you considered using alternative technologies, like Flash? I'm no that into IE but maybe it offers platform specific interfaces to audio, so that may also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

As constantinius says, jquery doesn't play sounds - the browser does. It's still early to assume that the majority of users will have an HTML5 capabie browser. in the meantime, the most portable (across browsers) way of playing audio files is using the embed tag.

If you need to support multiple different file types then convert them serverside using (e.g.) ffmpeg.

Trying to implement support for different filetypes would be possible using a java appplet or flash (but I suspect the altter will require a lot more work than the former).

Comment: mainly i have 3gp and mov format so what would be the easy way to do so.google and yahoo player are best but they need mp3 format not 3gp.so what u suggest me to do

Comment: "If you need to support multiple different file types then convert them serverside using (e.g.) ffmpeg."

Answer (score 0):

The quicktime player will play all of those formats, the only downside is that your users will have to install the quicktime plugin if they don't already have it.

Unfortunately Flash does not support all of these formats so you won't be able to use a flash player, which is already installed more often than not.